# WSO2-IS-5.6: LastPasswordUpdate & lastLogin in epoch format instead of ISO

Tags: timestamp, epoch, claims, wso2-identity-server

I set claims in WSO2-IS in order to display the lastLogin and lastPasswordUpdate(1). They are displayed but in epoch format. I would like to have them like other timestamp available in http://wso2.org/claims like "Last Modified Time" (2) [Example of what is displayed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WTmY8.png)

Any idea would be welcome.

Thanx.

Pascal

WOS2-IS version 5.6.0

Answer (score 1):

`lastModified` is probably populated by the AD/LDAP server itself upon updating the entity. Hence the different format. `lastLogin` and `lastPasswordUpdate` claims are populated from the Identity Server itself and this is the preferred format there.

Though we can change the format of this value(Using an extension point), that would break other features which rely on this value and only aware of this format to perform calculations.

From the description, it seems you are trying to monitor the activities of a particular user from the management console. Instead, you can use [SCIM2 rest APIs](https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS560/apidocs/SCIM2-endpoints/#!/operations#UsersEndpoint#getUserbyID) to obtain user information(claims) and then format the timestamp value to whatever the format you want. This approach would be something outside of Identity Server's management console.

Comment: Thank you. I will follow your advise to use SCIM2 rest APIs, as I do not want to break any features which use these values in WSO2-IS. Thanx again !